# SASS undefined variable

Tags: variables, sass

So I came across this problem. I have several sass files. The structure looks like this:

```
/scss
/scss/style.scss
/scss/partials/_variables.scss
/scss/page/header.scss
/scss/page/container.scss
/scss/page/footer.scss
```

And the content of style.scss file looks like this:

```
//SASS version used 3.4.13
//Partials
@import 'partials/variables';

//Import base structure elements
@import 'page/header';
@import 'page/container';
@import 'page/footer';
```

In my _variables.scss file I have one test variable which is $primary: #000; and in my header.scss file I have a syntax:

```
body {
  background: $primary;
}
```

That's all about scenario. The problem is that if I change something in my header.scss file and save it sass preprocessor throws an error:

error scss/page/header.scss (Line 4: Undefined variable: "$primary".)

If I change anything in my _variables.scss file and save it then all the css generation works fine.

I watch my sass files with command: sass --watch scss:css/

What might cause this problem?

Comment: Surely this `@import 'partials/variables';` should be this: `@import 'partials/_variables.scss';` ?

Comment: Rename your header.scss to _header.scss

Comment: @Novocaine definitely not

Comment: @Pik_at yep, this is it, and it applies to all other files, which shouldn't be generated